# I am unable to scrape all the data from the website as it is not loading

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The website I am scraping loads more data when scrolled down but I am unable to gather all the data because of that.

I tried to use the Selenium framework to automate the web browser an scroll down but there is a problem.

This is my code

```
selenium_service = Service('path_to_chromedriver')
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless') 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=selenium_service, options=chrome_options)

url = "https://www.tender247.com/keyword/mall+Tenders"
driver.get(url)

scroll_pause_time = 2
scroll_limit = 10 
scroll_count = 0

while scroll_count < scroll_limit:
    driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'body').send_keys(Keys.END)
    time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)
    scroll_count += 1

page_source = driver.page_source

driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html5lib')

table = soup.find('p', attrs={'id': 'pReqBrief'})
table2 = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'fontColor'})
prices = table2.find_all_next('p', attrs={'style': 'text-align: center'})

results = []

for row in table.find_all_next('p', attrs={'id': 'pReqBrief'}):
    data = {}
    data['Brief'] = row.text.strip()

    link = row.find_previous('a')['onclick'].split("'")[1]

    data['Link'] = f"https://www.tender247.com{link}"
    data['Price'] = prices[count].text.strip().replace('\n', '')

    results.append(data)

workbook = Workbook()
sheet = workbook.active

headers = ['Brief', 'Link', 'Price']

for col_num, header in enumerate(headers, start=1):
    cell = sheet.cell(row=1, column=col_num)
    cell.value = header
    cell.font = Font(bold=True)
    cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')

for row_num, data in enumerate(results, start=2):
    for col_num, header in enumerate(headers, start=1):
        cell = sheet.cell(row=row_num, column=col_num)
        if header == 'Link':
            cell.value = data[header]
            cell.hyperlink = data[header]
        else:
            cell.value = data[header]

for col_num in range(1, len(headers) + 1):
    column_letter = get_column_letter(col_num)
    sheet.column_dimensions[column_letter].width = 20

workbook.save('output.xlsx')
```

[This is the problem I am facing. It says JQuery not defined and Cannot read properties of undefined(ignore the count error I fixed it).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAza2.png)

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve with the "scroll" loop? Maybe also explain what your ultimate objective is

Comment: I am trying to scroll down into the webpage using that scroll loop I created so that additional content loads for me to scrape otherwise only 20 listings of tenders are being scraped by my code but actually, there are many more. My ultimate objective is to scrape all the data into an Excel file as I have implemented in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can scroll to the end of a page:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver

IW = 5
URL = 'https://www.tender247.com/keyword/mall+Tenders'
SCROLL_PAUSE = 0.5
SCROLL = 'window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);'
HEIGHT = 'return document.body.scrollHeight'

(options := webdriver.ChromeOptions()).add_argument("--headless")
service = Service('/Volumes/G-Drive/chromedriver')

def scroll(driver: WebDriver):
    print('Scrolling...', end='', flush=True)
    prev = -1
    while True:
        driver.execute_script(SCROLL)
        sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE)
        if (current := driver.execute_script(HEIGHT)) == prev:
            break
        prev = current
    print('done')

with webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options) as driver:
    driver.implicitly_wait(IW)
    driver.get(URL)
    scroll(driver)
    count = 0
    for tr in driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'tender_inner_tr'):
        try:
            table = tr.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'table')
            trs = table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')
            if len(trs) > 1:
                a = trs[1].find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')
                if a:
                    print(a.get_attribute('onclick'))
                    count += 1
        except Exception:
            pass
    print(f'{count=}')
```

**Output:**

```
Scrolling...done
viewTenderDetails('/TenderDetails/65933940');
viewTenderDetails('/TenderDetails/66649727');
viewTenderDetails('/TenderDetails/66132073');
```

...

```
viewTenderDetails('/TenderDetails/66462488');
viewTenderDetails('/TenderDetails/66466281');
viewTenderDetails('/TenderDetails/66698182');
count=306
```

Comment: Still the same issue I encountered before(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAza2.png) and still it is scraping only 20 listings.

Comment: but this time the Scrolling.... done is being printed.

Comment: Then the problem is elsewhere in your code. I will extend this answer to demonstrate my observations

Comment: Yeah maybe you are right, maybe scrolling isn't the problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You do need to scroll in order to be able to access all of the data. The way you're trying to access it (even after scrolling) is currently flawed